# I want to call the object in the data.json file

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, object

I want to call the object in the `data.json` file

[image: My File]

as an example in my `getData.js`:

```
var data = JSON.parse(data.json);
alert(data['name']);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is this just javascript application or Nodejs application ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This would be a very good time to read through [ask]. The details provided are extremely thin and open to a lots of different interpretations. After reading through that link edit the question with a properly detailed problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodejs 
You need to require fs which is library help to work with files. Then read the file.
    
    `var fs = require('fs');
    var obj;
    fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
     if (err) throw err;
     obj = JSON.parse(data);
     });`

Using jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

`$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
});`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get a value from a JSON object, I used a dummy JSON object from jsonplaceholder https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

```js
dummyData = [
{
id: 1,
name: "Leanne Graham",
username: "Bret",
email: "Sincere@april.biz",
address: {
street: "Kulas Light",
suite: "Apt. 556",
city: "Gwenborough",
zipcode: "92998-3874",
geo: {
lat: "-37.3159",
lng: "81.1496"
}
},
phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
website: "hildegard.org",
company: {
name: "Romaguera-Crona",
catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
bs: "harness real-time e-markets"
}
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Ervin Howell",
username: "Antonette",
email: "Shanna@melissa.tv",
address: {
street: "Victor Plains",
suite: "Suite 879",
city: "Wisokyburgh",
zipcode: "90566-7771",
geo: {
lat: "-43.9509",
lng: "-34.4618"
}
},
phone: "010-692-6593 x09125",
website: "anastasia.net",
company: {
name: "Deckow-Crist",
catchPhrase: "Proactive didactic contingency",
bs: "synergize scalable supply-chains"
}
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Clementine Bauch",
username: "Samantha",
email: "Nathan@yesenia.net",
address: {
street: "Douglas Extension",
suite: "Suite 847",
city: "McKenziehaven",
zipcode: "59590-4157",
geo: {
lat: "-68.6102",
lng: "-47.0653"
}
},
phone: "1-463-123-4447",
website: "ramiro.info",
company: {
name: "Romaguera-Jacobson",
catchPhrase: "Face to face bifurcated interface",
bs: "e-enable strategic applications"
}
},
{
id: 4,
name: "Patricia Lebsack",
username: "Karianne",
email: "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
address: {
street: "Hoeger Mall",
suite: "Apt. 692",
city: "South Elvis",
zipcode: "53919-4257",
geo: {
lat: "29.4572",
lng: "-164.2990"
}
},
phone: "493-170-9623 x156",
website: "kale.biz",
company: {
name: "Robel-Corkery",
catchPhrase: "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
bs: "transition cutting-edge web services"
}
},
{
id: 5,
name: "Chelsey Dietrich",
username: "Kamren",
email: "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
address: {
street: "Skiles Walks",
suite: "Suite 351",
city: "Roscoeview",
zipcode: "33263",
geo: {
lat: "-31.8129",
lng: "62.5342"
}
},
phone: "(254)954-1289",
website: "demarco.info",
company: {
name: "Keebler LLC",
catchPhrase: "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
bs: "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
}
},
{
id: 6,
name: "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
username: "Leopoldo_Corkery",
email: "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
address: {
street: "Norberto Crossing",
suite: "Apt. 950",
city: "South Christy",
zipcode: "23505-1337",
geo: {
lat: "-71.4197",
lng: "71.7478"
}
},
phone: "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
website: "ola.org",
company: {
name: "Considine-Lockman",
catchPhrase: "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
bs: "e-enable innovative applications"
}
},
{
id: 7,
name: "Kurtis Weissnat",
username: "Elwyn.Skiles",
email: "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
address: {
street: "Rex Trail",
suite: "Suite 280",
city: "Howemouth",
zipcode: "58804-1099",
geo: {
lat: "24.8918",
lng: "21.8984"
}
},
phone: "210.067.6132",
website: "elvis.io",
company: {
name: "Johns Group",
catchPhrase: "Configurable multimedia task-force",
bs: "generate enterprise e-tailers"
}
},
{
id: 8,
name: "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
username: "Maxime_Nienow",
email: "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
address: {
street: "Ellsworth Summit",
suite: "Suite 729",
city: "Aliyaview",
zipcode: "45169",
geo: {
lat: "-14.3990",
lng: "-120.7677"
}
},
phone: "586.493.6943 x140",
website: "jacynthe.com",
company: {
name: "Abernathy Group",
catchPhrase: "Implemented secondary concept",
bs: "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
}
},
{
id: 9,
name: "Glenna Reichert",
username: "Delphine",
email: "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
address: {
street: "Dayna Park",
suite: "Suite 449",
city: "Bartholomebury",
zipcode: "76495-3109",
geo: {
lat: "24.6463",
lng: "-168.8889"
}
},
phone: "(775)976-6794 x41206",
website: "conrad.com",
company: {
name: "Yost and Sons",
catchPhrase: "Switchable contextually-based project",
bs: "aggregate real-time technologies"
}
},
{
id: 10,
name: "Clementina DuBuque",
username: "Moriah.Stanton",
email: "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
address: {
street: "Kattie Turnpike",
suite: "Suite 198",
city: "Lebsackbury",
zipcode: "31428-2261",
geo: {
lat: "-38.2386",
lng: "57.2232"
}
},
phone: "024-648-3804",
website: "ambrose.net",
company: {
name: "Hoeger LLC",
catchPhrase: "Centralized empowering task-force",
bs: "target end-to-end models"
}
}
]

console.log(dummyData[2].name); // Clementine Bauch

alert(dummyData[5].company.name) // Considine-Lockman
```